# Comment notification grows too large with multiple digits

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, global-inbox

See picture. The number of notifications flows into the “Stack Exchange” text when I have > 10 notifications.

Furthermore, aligning the baseline of the number and “Stack Exchange” looks kind of weird. It would look better to center the red blob vertically (but that’s unrelated to the number of digits).

[image: screenshot of two-digit notification]

EDIT (not by OP):
Looks even worse with a three-digit number:

[image: screenshot of three-digit notification]

*"tackExchange: The Internet's #1 pushpin enthusiast site! Buy/Sell/Trade!"*

Comment: Just visit these sites more often…

Comment: @Marcel: these 16 comments happened between yesterday evening and today morning. I need some sleep, you know … ;-) (That said, this is the first time I’ve ever had > 10 unread comments.)

Comment: @PopularDemand We can just constantly ping @Marc and co. in the chat to remind them to fix this :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a certain amount of unavoidable expansion from 1 to 2 digits. Note that we disallow 3 digits here so **you will never see more than 99 messages indicated in the global inbox**, even if there are hundreds.

(I believe there is also a sanity cap on the global inbox anyway, so you can't ever read hundreds of messages.)

Comment: I agree - why don't you retag this with [status-bydesign] then? :-)