# the red numeric indicator in global inbox is too small

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox

Would it be much uglier to make it at least twice as big?

Comment: Why do you care about the number itself? I usually just understand that I have "some" notifications, and click it. No need to be able to read the particular number.

Comment: I wasn't really referring to the number itself actually, but rather the balloon (it's too small). The number is readable.

Comment: And yet... [Comment notification grows too large with multiple digits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71332/comment-notification-grows-too-large-with-multiple-digits)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I would agree that this indicator is a little small, especially on iDevices. On the iPad, for example, I have to scroll in to tap it and then scroll out to see the inbox.

The iOS devices can be laggy at times and if I tap the text in the Super Multi Collider before the page is completely loaded, it takes me to Stackexchange.com. I want to see my inbox, so I zoom in all the way, tap the balloon and then zoom out. That's inconvenient.